# Checking if user is online or not (updating activity time on each page visit)

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

So basically, I have a cronjob, that will check user database activity time, and if user has not done anything in last 10 minutes, it will automatically logout user and set it's status to offline.

Now about the hard part - On each user page visit, I'm doing an update to database, and inserting new activityTime, for example, if he visits homepage, database will automatically update, if he will go to users online page, again, the database will update e.c. That happens to all of users.

So the question is - is there any other, better solutions, or this is good enough solution for that?

Can it cause any troubles in long term, or will it reduce the website speed cause of too many db connections?

Hope you understood what I ment :)!

Comment: that's a common way, you can find others with a little research. It could reduce website speed if you have a lot of users and or poor hardware - but its no answerable as an absolute.

Comment: @Dagon , So you are saying, that this is not the worst idea, how to create this type of system, yes?

Comment: not the worse, seen it done; if your site is not huge, its quite a reasonable approach

Comment: Okay, I will leave the question, open, just in case. But thank you for  information ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly having sessions last 10 minutes, and send a simple `UPDATE` on each page load isn't a big deal. I can promise you that there are far more worse way to overload your database than this. For instance every time you need a value from the user, to extract it from the database every time instead of storing all the values through cookies or global values.

Don't worry about this approach since it will only require 1 more command per session. Some codes can run 25 *unnecessary* queries per page request without the programmer realizing it.

---

If you wish to have a number saying how many is online, simply run this through cron aswell:

```
$str_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-10 Minutes'));

$query = $this->db->query("
SELECT COUNT(*) AS online
FROM users
WHERE last_online >= ?
", array($str_time));

if ($query->num_rows())
    $int_online = $query->row()->online;
else $int_online = 0;

// Save into database, .json file or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

If your site logins are session/cookie based, you can just set the session/cookie timeout to be 10 minutes, then update that timeout/expiration each time someone visits a new page.  This method would be less intensive, but also not as secure as someone could modify the cookie.

I have done this in the past with good success.